# How to remove iPhone <button> styling?

Tags: iphone, html, css, button, mobile

http://ingoodtastemag.com/

On an iPhone, the button is round with a gradient. However, on every other desktop browser and Android that we've tested so far, it is square. I want the button to stay square. What CSS resets do I need for this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This rounded corner is the default property of the Safari browser and iOS 5 devices. To overwrite it, use the following styling for your button:

```css
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0;
```

Comment: the -webkit-appearance none helped remove the gradient

Answer (score 1):

To keep your own border radius while removing the iOS styling

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-border-radius: none;
border-radius: 10px;
```

You must remove webkit's border-radius to get your own style back, but you can still add your own border-radius **after** you remove theirs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this property on your button attribute.

```
border-radius: 0
```