# How to remove Default Button and Form Styling on Safari / iOS?

Tags: css, ios, iphone, button

After searching and trying everything, I can't get rid of the iOS style on my form.

[Here is what I have on PC / Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJd7O.jpg)

[And on Iphone 11 ( iOs 14.x )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxCry.jpg)

**HTML Code:**

```
<form method="post" >
        <fieldset style= "border-width: 0px;" >             

        
    <input style="font-size : 30px; height:48px; width:50px;" type="text" name="pone" id="pone" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;
            <input style="font-size : 30px; height:48px; width:50px;" type="text" name="ptwo" id="ptwo" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;
                    <input style="font-size : 30px; height:48px; width:50px;" type="text" name="pthree" id="pthree" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;
                            <input style="font-size : 30px; height:48px; width:50px;" type="text" name="pfour" id="pfour" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;
                                    <input style="font-size : 30px; height:48px; width:50px;" type="text" name="pfive" id="pfive" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;
            
            
            
            <label>
                <INPUT style="width:250px; height:50px; font-size : 30px" class="submit" type="submit" name="envoyer" id="envoyer" value="&nbsp; &nbsp; SE LIBERER &nbsp; &nbsp; ">
            </label><br /><br />
        </fieldset>
```

**And my CSS:**

```css
input {
border-radius: 0;
}

input[type=text], input[type=button], input[type=submit] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
```

I tried also only *input{*  and *input[type]{*
Any tips here to have the same result than Android ?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874336/how-to-remove-iphone-button-styling https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449412/styling-input-buttons-for-ipad-and-iphone

Comment: @quantumPuter Thank you for you very constructive answer. Could you please point out which part should I use that I not already tried in my CSS?
Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
input {
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;

}
input[type=text], input[type=button], input[type=submit] {   
    background-color : #D3D3D3;    
}
```

```html
<form method="post" >
   <fieldset style= "border-width: 0px;" >             
      </label>
      <input style="font-size : 30px; height:48px; width:50px;" type="text" name="pone" id="pone" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;
      <input style="font-size : 30px; height:48px; width:50px;" type="text" name="ptwo" id="ptwo" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;
      <input style="font-size : 30px; height:48px; width:50px;" type="text" name="pthree" id="pthree" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;
      <input style="font-size : 30px; height:48px; width:50px;" type="text" name="pfour" id="pfour" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;
      <input style="font-size : 30px; height:48px; width:50px;" type="text" name="pfive" id="pfive" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;
      </label>        
      <label>
      <INPUT style="width:250px; height:50px; font-size : 30px" class="submit" type="submit" name="envoyer" id="envoyer" value="&nbsp; &nbsp; SE LIBERER &nbsp; &nbsp; ">
      </label><br /><br />
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tried and here is the result:
https://i.ibb.co/hHxKDnq/barcode.png

The code seems to do something! No more rounded edges and good position, but the button is empty?

Comment: What do you mean that the button is empty?  You can't see the text "SE LIBERER"?

Comment: Yes! The page background is black, and the button should be grey like this, right ?( android screenshot )https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJd7O.jpg that's why I think the button is kind of... transparent?

Comment: Take a look now.  Please edit your question to make it more clear exactly how you want your button to look.  Use words instead of pictures.  Also, provide the HTML code that makes the page black.